# Creating loop within Unix Script

Tags: bash, unix, loops

I'm curious of how I might go about creating a more detailed output within the same scripting file. I would like to modify the script so that after it finds the matching line for the currency code, it outputs the following:

```
Currency code: {currency code value}     
Currency name: {currency name value}   
Units per USD: {units value}
USD per unit : {USD value}
```

What I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set local variable $cc to first command line argument, if present
cc=$1
# execute the do loop while $curr is blank
while [ -z "$curr" ]
do
# test if $cc is blank.  If so, prompt for a value
    if [ -z "$cc" ]
    then
        echo -n "Enter a currency code: "
        read cc
    fi
    # Search for $cc as a code in the curr.tab file
    curr=`grep "^$cc" curr.tab`
    # clear cc in case grep found no match and the loop should be repeated
    cc=
done
# echo the result
echo $curr
```

The curr.tab I am using would look something like this:

```
USD US Dollar          1.0000000000 1.0000000000
EUR Euro               0.7255238463 1.3783144484
GBP British Pound      0.6182980743 1.6173428992
INR Indian Rupee      61.5600229886 0.0162443084
AUD Australian Dollar  1.0381120551 0.9632871472
CAD Canadian Dollar    1.0378792155 0.9635032527
AED Emirati Dirham     3.6730001428 0.2722570000
MYR Malaysian Ringgit  3.1596464286 0.3164911083
```

Comment: This smells like "please do my work for me", rather than a specific, focused question about shell programming. Can you ask a tighter, more specific question?

Comment: I wish I got homework like this at school/university...

Comment: Doubtful. Trying to brush up on unix scripting since its been a while. I figure its best to start with the basics again. Pulled some example file. But it a bit troublesome. I'm trying to create multiple loops within the same scripting file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end, instead of `echo $curr` do:

```
[[ $curr =~ ^(...)[[:space:]]+(.+)([[:space:]]+([[:digit:]\.]+)){2}$ ]]
printf "Currency code: %s\nCurrency name: %s\nUnits per USD: %s\nUSD per unit : %s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
```